# count unique combinations of values

Tags: r, unique, combinations

My dataframe looks like this:

```
ID | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4
1  |    M    |    D    |    F    |   A
2  |    F    |    M    |    G    |   B
3  |    M    |    D    |    F    |   A
4  |    L    |    D    |    E    |   B
```

I want to get something like this.

```
value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4|  Number of combinations
  M     |    D    |    F    |   A    |     2
  F     |    M    |    G    |   B    |     1
  L     |    D    |    E    |   B    |     1
```

e.g. to count the number of unique combinations of the columns value 1 - value 4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`count` in `plyr` package will do that task.

```
> df
  ID   value.1   value.2   value.3 value.4
1  1     M         D         F           A
2  2     F         M         G           B
3  3     M         D         F           A
4  4     L         D         E           B
> library(plyr)
> count(df[, -1])
    value.1   value.2   value.3 value.4 freq
1     F         M         G           B    1
2     L         D         E           B    1
3     M         D         F           A    2
```

Answer (score 13):

```
N <- 10000

d <- data.frame(
  ID=seq(1, N), 
  v1=sample(c("M","F", "M", "L"), N, replace = TRUE), 
  v2=sample(c("D","M","D","D"), N, replace = TRUE), 
  v3=sample(c("F","G","F","E"), N, replace = TRUE),
  v4=sample(c("A","B","A","B"), N, replace = TRUE)
)
```

#### With data.table (fastest)

```
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(d)
dt[, .N, by = c('v1','v2','v3','v4')]
```

#### With dplyr

```
dplyr::count_(d, vars = c('v1','v2','v3','v4'))
```

#### With plyr

```
plyr::count(d, vars = c('v1','v2','v3','v4'))
plyr::ddply(d, .variables = c('v1','v2','v3','v4'), nrow)
```

#### With aggregate (slowest)

```
aggregate(ID ~ ., d, FUN = length)
```

#### Benchmark

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(dt[, .N, by = c('v1','v2','v3','v4')],
                               plyr::count(d, vars = c('v1','v2','v3','v4')),
                               plyr::ddply(d, .variables = c('v1','v2','v3','v4'), nrow),
                               dplyr::count_(d, vars = c('v1','v2','v3','v4')),
                               aggregate(ID ~ ., d, FUN = length), 
                               times = 1000)

Unit: microseconds
                                                         expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq        max neval  cld
                     dt[, .N, by = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4")]  887.807 1107.543  1263.777 1174.258  1289.724   4263.156  1000 a   
             plyr::count(d, vars = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4")) 3912.791 4270.387  5379.080 4498.053  5791.743 157146.103  1000   c 
 plyr::ddply(d, .variables = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"), nrow) 7737.874 8553.370 10630.849 9018.266 11126.517 187301.696  1000    d
           dplyr::count_(d, vars = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4")) 2126.913 2432.957  2763.499 2568.251  2789.386  12549.669  1000  b  
                           aggregate(ID ~ ., d, FUN = length) 7395.440 8121.828 10546.659 8776.371 10858.263 210139.759  1000    d
```

It seems best to simply use `data.table` instead of the `data.frame` as it is fastest and doesn't need an other function or library to count. Note also that `aggregate` function performs much slower on large data sets.

*Final note: feel free to update with new methods.*

Comment: I think you should show the results for a somewhat larger data set. Also, I guess `plyr::count(d, c('v1','v2','v3','v4'))` might be correct, after looking at `args(plyr::count)`. There is probably also a `dplyr::count` that could be considered.

Comment: @Frank, it is now based on 10k rows.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One other point: `length(ID)` doesn't seem like it would give the correct result now, since `ID` repeats values. It's generally a good idea to test for equality of results across the methods. Oh never mind, I guess it doesn't matter what values it has. Fwiw, the reason data.table is fast is documented in `?GForce`.

Comment: They give a different format, but `tapply(d$ID, d[, -1], length)` and `table(d[, -1])` are also fast for this particular case.

Answer (score 6):

Without plyr.

```
aggregate(ID ~ ., d, FUN=length)# . means all variables in d except ID
```

Comment: Nice, but very (!!) slow compared to plyr::count. From `microbenchmark` test with 4000x500 DF summarizing frequencies for 3 columns, its seems that `count` is 20x (!) faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using the `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
d <- data.frame(
    ID=seq(1,4), v1=c("M","F", "M", "L"), 
    v2=c("D","M","D","D"), v3=c("F","G","F","E"), v4=c("A","B","A","B")
)
ddply(d,.(v1,v2,v3,v4), nrow)
```

I hope this was not homework...