# Finding reciprocity among the data elements

Tags: r

I have a 3 column data which looks like below:

RowID   callerid       item_id  contributor 
28476   919471180334    1014038 911111111111
28477   919471180334    1026448 919939727689
28478   919471180334    1026334 918002321300
28479   919471180334    1026177 911111111111
28480   919471180334    1026063 919934520183
28481   919471180334    1026155 919939727689

There are hundreds of records. I need to find the reciprocity among the element of column caller id and contributor id. It means how many cases a callerID listened to item posted by contributor and vice versa. is there any direct function that can be useful in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count unique combinations of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862105/count-unique-combinations-of-values)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(
~RowID,  ~callerid, ~item_id, ~contributor,
28476, 919471180334, 1014038, 911111111111,
28477, 919471180334, 1026448, 919939727689,
28478, 919471180334, 1026334, 918002321300,
28479, 919471180334, 1026177, 911111111111,
28480, 919471180334, 1026063, 919934520183,
28481, 919471180334, 1026155, 919939727689)


dat %>% group_by(callerid, contributor) %>%  summarise(n=n())
# `summarise()` regrouping output by 'callerid' (override with `.groups` argument)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   callerid [1]
#       callerid  contributor     n
#          <dbl>        <dbl> <int>
# 1 919471180334 911111111111     2
# 2 919471180334 918002321300     1
# 3 919471180334 919934520183     1
# 4 919471180334 919939727689     2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(item_id = rep(919471180334, 6),
           contributor = c(911111111111,919939727689,918002321300,911111111111,919934520183,919939727689))
```

A base R solution:

```
as.data.frame(table(df))

   item_id  contributor Freq
1 919471180334 911111111111    2
2 919471180334 918002321300    1
3 919471180334 919934520183    1
4 919471180334 919939727689    2
```

or with `plyr`

```
plyr::count(df)

       item_id  contributor freq
1 919471180334 911111111111    2
2 919471180334 918002321300    1
3 919471180334 919934520183    1
4 919471180334 919939727689    2
```

Difference is, that `plyr::count` does not include combinations with zero counts, which makes no difference for your case.